# Why this python if is not working

Tags: python-2.7

Hello I am learning Python and now I am learning Python2.7 if condition. I have written the following code for testing the if conditions work, which should print the first if condition if I input greater than 4 and will print if I enter less than 4 but the script is always printing the first (Hello the digit is greater than 4) also when I enter a digit less than 4. What's the wrong? But if I declare the variables in the script except the input then it is working fine.

```
  name=raw_input("Enter your name:>>>")

  print "Welcome %r you will now work with Python IF Condition "%name

  digit=raw_input("Enter a digit")

  if digit>4:
     print "Hello the digit is greater than 4"

 else :
     print "Not valid"
```

Answer (score 2):

`raw_input()` returns a string. Convert it to a number:

```
digit = int(raw_input("Enter a digit"))
```

(You could also use `input()`, but I think the above is a little cleaner in that you explicitly state you're expecting an integer.)